# Use of "only" as modifier

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

1. I think, serving only “in-restaurant” food is a great idea.
2. My restaurant would only be offering foods in the restaurant.

Are these two sentences grammatically correct?
Is "in-restaurant" a valid phrasal verb?

Comment: Personally I find the alternative "My restaurant would be offering foods only in the restaurant." to be clearer, where the modifier "only" appears directly before what it is modifying/emphasising.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these two sentences grammatically correct?

Both your sentences are fine, except the comma after "I think" should not be used.  It makes it seem like you are starting a new sentence and leaving "I think" dangling as a sentence on its own.

> Is "in-restaurant" a valid phrasal verb

A phrasal verb is a verb like *write up* - a verb with 2 (sometimes 3) words, and the second (and third if present) word are otherwise normally a preposition but function as adverbs in these case (a term used to describe these extra words is also "particles").  "In-restaurant" is an adjective modifying *food*.

*In-restaurant* is a valid way to express what you are trying to say.  By including the quotes you are acknowledging that you are "building" inventing a term from parts not normally combined.  This is the correct thing to do.

*Dine-in* is a term I've seen on a lot of receipts, in places in the US I've lived, from restaurants to say you did not order your food "to go" or "take-out".  You could say "We should take dine-in orders only."

I've never heard @user3169's "eat-in" myself but it's possible that in other areas of the U.S. or other English speaking areas this term is common.

Answer (score 0):

> in-restaurant

is not a usually used phrase. If a restaurant wants to restrict food to only food they serve, they might use the phrasing

> Outside food is prohibited.

as is the policy in many airport lounges.

If you are only offering food for consumption within the restaurant, you might say

> No take outs. *(AmE)*
>   No take aways *(BrE*)

meaning food is not packaged to be taken to another place to be eaten.

To be clear about your offering, you might say

> We only prepare food to be eaten on-premises.